# Dapper: mapping hierarchy and single different property

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I really love Dapper's simplicity and possibilities. I would like to use Dapper to solve common challenges I face on a day-to-day basis. These are described below.

Here is my simple model.

```
public class OrderItem {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public Money PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public Money SellingPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long? CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Vendor
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Money Balance { get; set; }
    public string SyncValue { get; set; }
}

public struct Money
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Two challenges have been stumping me.

**Question 1:**
Should I always create a DTO with mapping logic between DTO-Entity in cases when I have a single property difference or simple enum/struct mapping?

For example: There is my Vendor entity, that has *Balance* property as a *struct* (otherwise it could be *Enum*). I haven't found anything better than that solution:

```
public async Task<Vendor> Load(long id) {
    const string query = @"
        select * from [dbo].[Vendor] where [Id] = @id
    ";

    var row = (await this._db.QueryAsync<LoadVendorRow>(query, new {id})).FirstOrDefault();
    if (row == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return row.Map();
}
```

In this method I have 2 overhead code:
1. I have to create *LoadVendorRow* as DTO object;
2. I have to write my own mapping between *LoadVendorRow* and *Vendor*:

```
public static class VendorMapper {
    public static Vendor Map(this LoadVendorRow row) {
        return new Vendor {
            Id = row.Id,
            Title = row.Title,
            Balance = new Money() {Amount = row.Balance, Currency = "RUR"},
            SyncValue = row.SyncValue
        };
    }
}
```

Perhaps you might suggest that I have to store amount & currency together and retrieve it like `_db.QueryAsync<Vendor, Money, Vendor>(...)`- Perhaps, you are right. In that case, what should I do if I need to store/retrive *Enum* (*OrderStatus* property)?

```
var order = new Order
{
    Id = row.Id,
    ExternalOrderId = row.ExternalOrderId,
    CustomerFullName = row.CustomerFullName,
    CustomerAddress = row.CustomerAddress,
    CustomerPhone = row.CustomerPhone,
    Note = row.Note,
    CreatedAtUtc = row.CreatedAtUtc,
    DeliveryPrice = row.DeliveryPrice.ToMoney(),
    OrderStatus = EnumExtensions.ParseEnum<OrderStatus>(row.OrderStatus)
};
```

Could I make this work without my own implementations and save time?

**Question 2:**
What should I do if I'd like to restore data to entities which are slightly more complex than simple single level DTO? *OrderItem* is beautiful example. This is the technique I am using to retrieve it right now:

```
public async Task<IList<OrderItem>> Load(long orderId) {
    const string query = @"
            select [oi].*,
                   [i].*,
                   [v].*,
                   [c].*
              from [dbo].[OrderItem] [oi]
              join [dbo].[Item] [i]
                on [oi].[ItemId] = [i].[Id]
              join [dbo].[Category] [c]
                on [i].[CategoryId] = [c].[Id]
              join [dbo].[Vendor] [v]
                on [oi].[VendorId] = [v].[Id]
             where [oi].[OrderId] = @orderId
    ";

    var rows = (await this._db.QueryAsync<LoadOrderItemRow, LoadItemRow, LoadVendorRow, LoadCategoryRow, OrderItem>(query, this.Map, new { orderId }));

    return rows.ToList();
}
```

As you can see, my **question 1** problem forces me write custom mappers and DTO for every entity in the hierarchy. That's my mapper:

```
private OrderItem Map(LoadOrderItemRow row, LoadItemRow item, LoadVendorRow vendor, LoadCategoryRow category) {
    return new OrderItem {
        Id = row.Id,
        Item = item.Map(category),
        Vendor = vendor.Map(),
        PurchasePrice = row.PurchasePrice.ToMoney(),
        SellingPrice = row.SellingPrice.ToMoney()
    };
}
```

There are lots of mappers that I'd like to eliminate to prevent unnecessary work.

Comment: Have you tried using something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ValueInjecter](https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) in order to map the objects automatically or you do not want to use any mappers at all?

Comment: You load the data from the db into `LoadVendorRow` and that has the `Balance` field. So what is it actually that is in your `Vendor` table? Does it have the Currency and Amount fields? Is the Balance field the same as the Amount field in your db? Also it seems like every time there is a "money/value" field you convert it to your `Money` struct. So is there always a "money + currency" fields in your DB? For example, DeliveryPrice and DeliveryPriceCurrency?

Comment: @pasty, no, i haven't tried it, but should it give me any benifits?

Comment: @vonv., you are right, Now i don't have currency column in database and i have to use my const currency property ("USD" for example), but even if i have it in database, it won't prevent me from writing my custom mapper.

Comment: My biggest problem right now, how should i read and map data from db to my domain entities (is there a clean way to retrive & map Order entity with relative properties like Vendor, Item, Category etc)

Comment: IMO yes - automapping would remove boiler plate mapping code. The specific mappings can still be configured separately.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a clean way to retrive & map Order
>   entity with relative properties like Vendor, Item, Category etc)

You are not showing your `Order` entity but I'll take your `OrderItem` as an example and show you that you don't need a mapping tool for the specific problem (as quoted). You can retrieve the `OrderItem`s along with the `Item` and `Vendor` info of each by doing the following:

```
var sql = @"
select oi.*, i.*, v.* 
from OrderItem 
    inner join Item i on i.Id = oi.ItemId
    left join Vendor v on v.Id = oi.VendorId
    left join Category c on c.Id = i.CategoryId";
var items = connection.Query<OrderItem, Item, Vendor, Category, OrderItem>(sql, 
    (oi,i,v,c)=>
    {
      oi.Item=i;oi.Item.Category=c;oi.Vendor=v;
      oi.Vendor.Balance = new Money { Amount = v.Amount, Currency = v.Currency};
      return oi; 
    });
```

NOTE: The use of `left join` and adjust it accordingly based on your table structure.

Comment: As you could notice, i couldn't retrive domain entities `OrderItem` and `Vendor` because it has `Balance` property, which one is struct and i have to write mapper. In this case, there aren't any difference from code i've already provided my question. I think that's is not clear way and try to find cleaner one

Comment: There's no stopping you from doing the mapping in the expression - see my edit `new Money`. That is assuming you have both the Amount and Currency in the database as you mentioned in your comment on your question.

Comment: Vendor doesn't have `Amount` property in database- there is `Balance` property with decimal type

Comment: You mentioned in comment thread in your question that you have the Amount in the database. But whatever the field name is you can swap it out in the code I gave. It's really best that you keep the naming in your tables and classes the same to avoid confusion and keep your naming standard (and the meaning of values ;). If you want to keep Balance in Vendor as a struct and keep it as Balance in your table then do an alias when you select like: `select v.Balance as Amount.... from Vendor....`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question a 100%. And the fact that no one has attempted to answer it yet, leads me to believe that I'm not alone when I say it might be a little confusing.

You mention that you love Dapper's functionality, but I don't see you using it in your examples. Is it that you want to develop an alternative to Dapper? Or that you don't know how to use Dapper in your code?

In any case, here's a link to Dapper's code base for your review:
https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Hoping that you'd be able to clarify your questions, I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: My question: how could dapper help me to work with domain entities, should i always write my own mapper code etc